# Including SO files without headers

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, glfw

I have recently involved myself in making a basic game engine.  I have decided to place all of my middleware into an `Externals` directory, where a bash script builds all my middleware into shared object files in the `Binaries` directory.

In my `CmakeLists.txt` file, I am able to link these libraries into my main executable, like so:

```
add_library (glfw SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties (glfw PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION 
  ${ENGINE_BINARIES_DIR}/Libraries/Shared/libglfw.so.3.2
)

...

target_link_libraries (Engine glfw)
```

However, when I try to include `GLFW/glfw3.h` in my main file, it fails to compile.  This makes sense, because there is no `glfw3.h` file; however, all other attempts at including glfw into my project have failed.

**TL ; DR**

What is the best way to include headers from an existing shared object library?  Is it possible to achieve this without an `includes/glfw` directory, or would one need to modify their code / project structure in order to load these functions?

Answer (score 2):

I realize my mistake now.

I did a bit of research on shared objects / DLL's and building GLFW before posting this question; however, I believe I was still rather confused as to what a shared library was and how it worked.

I now realize that you *do*, in fact, need to include the header file; as it contains the *declarations* of the middleware code, while the `libglfw.so.3.2` library contained the *definitions* of the code.

I have thus solved my issue by keeping the .so file in the `Libraries/Shared` directory and the GLFW header file in the `External` directory, and using CMake to point the compiler / linker to both.